# BASH: grep characters and replace by the same plus tab

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

Basically, the only thing I need is to replace two spaces by a tab; this is the query:

```
abc def ghi K00001  jkl
```

all the columns are separated by a tab; the `K00001 jkl` is separated by *two spaces*. But I want these two spaces to be replaced by a tab.
I cannot just grep all two spaces since other contents have to spaces and they should stay.

My approach would be to `grep`:

```
grep '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]  ' file
```

but I want to replace it to have the same `K00001<TAB>jkl`

How do I replace by the same string? Can I use variables to store the grep result and then print the modified (tab not spaces) by the same string?

Comment: somehting like this `echo -e 'aa\tbb\tcc  dd' |sed 's/\s\s/\t/'` ???

Comment: `cannot just grep all two spaces since other contents have to spaces and they should stay.` How are you differentiating the `other content` with actual content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed -E $'s/([^[:blank:]]) {2}([^[:blank:]])/\\1\t\\2/g' file
```

Regex `([^[:blank:]]) {2}([^[:blank:]])` makes sure to match 2 spaces surrounded by 2 non-space characters. In replacement we put back surrounding characters using back-references `\1` and `\2`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -r "s/([A-Z][0-9]{5})  /&\t/" File
```

or

```
sed -r "s/([A-Z][0-9]{5})\s{2}/&\t/" File
```

Example :

```
AMD$ echo "abc def ghi K00001  jkl" | sed -r "s/([A-Z][0-9]{5})  /&\t/"
abc def ghi K00001      jkl
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use awk , since with awk no matter if fields are separated by one - two or more spaces i can force output to be with tabs:

```
$ echo "abc def ghi K00001  jkl" |awk -v OFS="\t" '{$1=$1}1'
abc     def     ghi     K00001  jkl
```